# How to secure web application with ManagementRealm in JBoss EAP 6.2?

Tags: security, jboss, jboss7.x, jaas, jboss-eap-6

Is there a way to secure web application with the same user and roles configuration that ManagementRealm?

I know that there is a security-domain "java:/jaas/other" that delegates to ApplicationRealm. How to create similar security-domain that delegates to ManagementRealm?

Other words - I want a web application to be accessible by same users that can access JBoss' Admin Console.

I'm running domain mode.

//Edit:

I was able to set-up security domain that refers to management realm by using login-module RealmDirect and setting realm=ManagementRealm
Authentication works fine, however it does not pick user roles. Exact same configuration for ApplicationRealm works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge. After defining a security domain that refers to "ManagementRealm" and defining the role in web.xml, the trick is to configure the ManagementRealm to map groups to roles:

authorization map-groups-to-roles="**true**"

```
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="true">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
```